# Gaussian deconvolution of a density curve

Tags: r, gaussian, deconvolution

I have a vector which I have made a density function for. It is a curve with multiple peaks, and I want to perform a **Gaussian deconvolution** in order to represent my density curve with multiple Gaussian curves. I am hoping there is a package that will allow me to do this, but I haven't found anything that has worked for me so far. I tried to follow the example given here (https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-mixture-distributions-with-the-r-package-mixtools/) but the vector I am working with is ~400 mb and won't play nicely with the mixtools package tools. I need something that will work with the size of the datasets I am working with or be able to work with the density curve directly. Any help appreciated, thank you!

I do not have sample data but I am happy to have it explained with the faithful dataset in R, I know I can find the density of `faithful$waiting` with density(`faithful$waiting`) and it plots just fine, but the deconvolution has me stuck.

Comment: if size seems to be the problem preventing you from using mixtools, you could try computing on a random subset of the vector (using function `sample(...)`)

Comment: Also, it would be sensible to sample more densely where the curve varies more strongly (e.g. near the peaks) and less densely where the curve is more flat. You could base your sampling decision on the distribution of the curve's first derivative.